# Clicking each link under a specific div - python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click each link in the ListNews div in the below website (chinalaborwatch).

I have done a bit of research and the following should have worked, but instead, it only clicks on one link and then it stops.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.chinalaborwatch.org/news")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div[2]'))).click()
```

What am I missing?

thanks!

Comment: But your code only click a url.....What did you want to do?

Comment: when I reach the page http://www.chinalaborwatch.org/news I want to click on each link and open it.

Comment: Open it on a new tab,Right?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to open each one of them, scrape the text, close the tab, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the url list firstly.Then visit them and scrape the data what you want:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.chinalaborwatch.org/news")

element_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#form1 > div:nth-child(5) > div > div.ListNews > div')
url_list = [element.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href') for element in element_list] # get all the url
for i in url_list:
    driver.get(i) # switch the url

    # then it is your work,scrape the text you want.
```